# Inherits Linkbutton

Tags: vb.net

I need to create a linkbutton to have special property. I found the code and follow it, but I got the error -end of statement expected. Would someone point it out to me?

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Web.UI


Public Class TempLinkButton  Inherits LinkButton
Private NewPropertyValue As String

Public Property NewProperty() As String
    Get
        Return NewPropertyValue
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As String)
        NewPropertyValue = value
    End Set
End Property

End Class
```

Comment: At what line exactly do you get the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place `Inherits LinkButton` in the line below the `Class` statement, like:

```
Public Class TempLinkButton
   Inherits LinkButton
```

This fixes your first error. However Linkbutton is part of the `WebControls` namespace in System.Web.UI, so if you did not import this namespace elsewhere you would need to write

```
Public Class TempLinkButton
   Inherits WebControls.LinkButton
```